Upgrade App to a newer com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps SDK version
I Udated my android kotlin application into playstore. after one day i got email from "Playstore" like
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps has reported play-services-maps:12.0.1 as outdated. You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.
But am not using any google play Services or Map related dependencies in my code(gradle file). Could anyone please check and help ?

Without posting app gradle file it difficult to answer you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
